# WebVR mobile browser screen timeout

Tags: three.js, webvr

Every WebVR app on Android I tried become completely useless after 30 second due to screen timeout in the browser. Is there anyway to prevent it?

Comment: Any comments mr. useless downvoter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a (somewhat hacky) solution for this](https://github.com/borismus/webvr-polyfill/blob/master/src/wakelock.js) that is being used by the webvr-poyfill.

Android doesn't go to sleep when a video is being played back, so even creating an invisble video-element and playing it will disable the inactive-timeout.

On iOS, a page navigation is initiated and immediately stopped every 30 seconds to keep the screen awake.

Also note that this problem will probably go away when chrome for android ships the real WebVR implementation (probably sometime later this year, when the new daydream-compatible pixel/pixel XL-phones are released)

Answer (score -1):

I think you might find that unless you're on desktop the browser itself is unable to keep the screen on. Instead this can only be sustained by a third party app, or more simply by the user directly through settings.

Simplest solution might be to ask user to adjust settings.